# make connection 2 database in cs-cart with join in the each table

Tags: php, mysql, cs-cart

I'm in confuse how to connection 2 database and make relation it using cs-cart.com is there a way to connected and relate it with code ? if been looking for better pratice but now where to be found

this is the similar code to connect with additional database but how do i how to make relation to other table in different database?

```
db_initiate($host, $user, $password, $name, $params = array());
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use database with another prefix. config-local.php setted one connection details for cms. Not two.

Comment: Is that possible to use 2 databases? And connection? Only 1 setting for database there